# When to unregister a delegate of a UIView or UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I got a customized UILabel which register itself to a communication instance during creation. This part works perfect, the UILabel will . But when I remove the UILabel will update itself after called by the communication instance. I have of course remove the listener delegate too. But as ViewDidUnload is not call anymore, I do not know where.

Here the code sample:

```
@implementation MyValueLabel
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", ((double)g_com.getRemoteValue())/100 ];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate addBalanceListener:self];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)communicationUpdate
{
        self.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", ((double)g_com.getRemoteValue())/100 ];
}

// This is the missing Method
-(void) DestructionOfTheLabelWhichIDidNotFound
{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate removeBalanceListener:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: You register in `init`. Therefore you should unregister in `dealloc`.

Comment: UILabel with Cocoa?  Never heard of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you seem to be looking for the `-dealloc` method which is called on an object when it is to be deallocated. However I do not believe that is an adequate solution.

The example provided here seems to be doing a number of unexpected things which I believe will result in code which is surprising to other developers, requires fighting against common patterns in the UIKit framework, and be difficult to maintain.

Normally iOS view controllers are responsible for mediating or coordinating how data reaches view objects. A controller supplies a view with either the data it should currently display or provides it with a source of that data. This allows a single view class to be used in many different locations and to display data of the same type regardless of its source. Instead here we have a view which reaches out to obtain it's own data. There's no way for a controller to determine when an instance of this view class should update or what data it should display. For example the controller cannot decide to pause updates, or cause other view elements to update at the same time.

In addition this view makes several assumptions about the source of it's data and how that source may be obtained. The view assumes that the current application's app delegate is specifically an `AppDelegate` class so it will not work if you want to use this view in another application. Since the view also obtains this `AppDelegate` instance via a call to `+ sharedApplication` there's no hint to users of this view that it has this dependency.

Consider instead allowing classes which use this view class to provide it with the data it should display.

Answer (score 0):

If the property where `addBalanceListener:` stores the reference is weak, you don't need to do anything. Weak properties are automatically set to nil when the instance they are pointing to is dealloced.